# Feature Engineering

Tags: dataset, pandas, feature-extraction, categorical-data, feature-engineering

I have a data frame with around 37,000 rows and 54 columns. Out of these 54 columns, two columns namely 'user_id' and 'mail_id' are provided in a very creepy format as shown below:

```
user_id                                           mail_id       
AR+tMy3H/E+Re8Id20zUIz+amJkv6KU12o+BrgIDin0=      DQ/4I+GIOz2ZoIiK0Lg0AkwnI35XotghgUK/MYc101I=
1P4AOvdzJzhDSHi7jJ3udWv4ajpKxOn4T/rCLv4PrXU=      BL3z4RtiyfIDydaRYWX2ZXL6IX10QH1yG5ak1s/8Lls=
OEfFUcsTAGInCfsHuLZuIgdSNtuNsg8EdfN98VUZVTs=      BL3z4RtiyfIDydaRYWX2ZXL6IX10QH1yG5ak1s/8Lls=   
1P4AOvdzJzhDSHi7jJ3udWv4ajpKxOn4T/rCLv4PrXU=      EHNBRbi6i9KO6cMHsuDPFjZVp2cY3RH+BiOKwPwzLQs=
CYRcuV0cR0algMZJ1N6+3uKcqi8iu+6tJNzmBbmgN7o=      K0y/NW59TJkYc5y0HUwDeAXrewYT0JQlkcozz0s2V5Q=
```

After a detailed analysis of my data, I figured out that I cannot drop these two columns from my data frame as they are too important for prediction. I can hash these two features but there is one more interesting thing. There are only 2,000 types of user_ids and mail_ids. So doing one hot encoding can help a lot. My question is that if I convert this into one hot encoding using 'get_dummies' method in pandas with `sparse = True`, will it be memory efficient or is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: Just do it; that's not a lot of data even for a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

@Nain, this is called a hard problem :)

One possible solution is called "Engineering Mixed Variables."
I've attached screenshot from a possible solution. Not everything out of fairness to the author. It's based on Soledad Galli's [Feature Engineering for Machine Learning](https://www.udemy.com/course/feature-engineering-for-machine-learning/) on Udemy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[@Student T](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/9123/student-t): Pandas can have memory issues with only a few thousand rows, depends on width and operation (`merge()` can be bad).

If you do have issues I've found moving to a database the least painful, just dump your dataframes to tables with [`DataFrame.to_sql()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and pull it back into your scikit-learn pipeline with [`pandas.read_sql_query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html)